# WordPress pagination not working on template search.php

Tags: wp-query, pagination, search

I have a small issue, pagination doesn't work on `search.php`.
I query the results with `wp_Query` using the code below,
I get to see the page link but when I press them I get 404 error. 
I was told that this happens becouse I query on the `search.php` page.

The code I'm using is taken from the [wp code pagination](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/paginate_links), Its a long query but what is important are these two lines:

```
$paged = ( get_query_var( 'paged' ) ) ? absint( get_query_var( 'paged' ) ) : 1;
```

and

```
'paged' => $paged,
```

**complete query**

```
if (isset($_GET['reg-prop-search-form'])){
    $paged = ( get_query_var( 'paged' ) ) ? absint( get_query_var( 'paged' ) ) : 1;


    $args = array(
        'posts_per_page' => 9,
        's' => $_GET['s'],
        'post_type'      => 'property',
        'paged' => $paged,
        'meta_query'     =>  array(
            'relation '  => 'AND',
            array(
                'key'       => 'prop_area',
                'value'     => $area,
                'compare'   => $area_val,
            ),
            array(
                'key'       => 'prop_city',
                'value'     => $city,
                'compare'   => $city_val,
            ),
            array(
                'key'       => 'prop_type',
                'value'     => $type,
                'compare'   => $type_val,
            ),
            array(
                'key'     => 'prop_rooms',
                'value'   => array( $fromrooms, $torooms ),
                'type'    => 'numeric',
                'compare' => 'BETWEEN',
            ),
            array(
                'key'     => 'prop_store',
                'value'   => array( $fromfloor, $tofloor ),
                'type'    => 'numeric',
                'compare' => 'BETWEEN',
            ),
            array(
                'key'     => 'prop_price',
                'value'   => array( $min, $max ),
                'type'    => 'numeric',
                'compare' => $equal,
            ),
        ),
    );  
};
```

**this is the loop**

```
$the_query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

.....

```
    <?php if( $the_query->have_posts() ): ?>
        <?php while( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post(); ?>


            <?php get_template_part( 'content', 'search' ); ?>

        <?php endwhile; ?>
    <div id="pagination">

        <?php

            $big = 999999999;
             echo paginate_links( array(
                'base' => str_replace( $big, '%#%', esc_url( get_pagenum_link( $big ) ) ),
                'format' => '?paged=%#%',
                'current' => max( 1, get_query_var('paged') ),
                'total' => $the_query->max_num_pages
            ) );
        ?>
        <?php echo paginate_links( $args ); ?>


    </div>
    <?php else : ?>

        <?php get_template_part( 'no-results', 'search' ); ?>

    <?php endif; ?>
    <?php wp_reset_query();  // Restore global post data stomped by the_post(). ?>
</div>
```

Comment: The 404 is hit before your template file is being selected. Use the global query and the action hook `pre_get_posts` to manipulate it.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I read the documentation. I am not using the global query, I am using wp_query. on which function should I use the `pre_get_post` you mantiond?

Comment: [pre_get_posts](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/pre_get_posts) is a global hook which allows you to use the global wp_query, so WP knows how many search results (and thus: search result pages) are available. There are examples you can adapt, but you can probably copy most of your code.